# Исследовательский центр Эймса — с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли писать название учреждения "Исследовательский центр Эймса" с прописной буквы или нет? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, правильно писать со строчной буквы, поскольку это не официальное название, которое заключают в кавычки. Посмотрите, в [статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%B0) о нём на Википедии в правой колонке тоже написано с маленькой буквы: *Карта исследовательского центра Эймса.*